# Triggering an exception in a main thread from a daemon thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

How do you trigger an exception in a main thread, running blocking code, from a daemon thread in Python?

I have a daemon thread that periodically checks a database for a record indicating that its current process should terminate (i.e. the user has pressed the "cancel" button). In my main non-daemon thread, I'm running a blocking call to an external process that I can't easily modify to gracefully terminate. However, the main thread can gracefully handle a normal KeyboardInterrupt when I manually trigger one.

So if my daemon thread receives the terminate command, how do I raise an exception in my main thread to terminate my process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the thread docs, I finally found the solution to be [interrupt_main()](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.interrupt_main).

Comment: The link should read : https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html

It is the rare solution to stopping Django from code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your subprocess returncode with the [returncode](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) attribute. Raise something if it's different from zero.

Edit: I've mixed up the subprocess and multiprocessing modules. There is however an [exitcode](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=daemon#multiprocessing.Process.exitcode) attribute in the multiprocessing module that seems similar to the subprocess returncode attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It's typically done using a message queue. 
See [Catch a thread's exception in the caller thread in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829329/catch-a-threads-exception-in-the-caller-thread-in-python)

However it will not preempt your main thread, you will have to actively poll for it. Maybe with signals you'll be able to get what you need.