# How to respond to exceptions in a thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, exception

I have some code running in a thread that I need to respond to any exceptions within the calling thread.  How would I find out if there are any exceptions and just reboot the child thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get exception with sth like this:

```
def run(self):
        while True:                
            try: #yourThread
            except Exception, e: print e
```

and for restarting a child check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2830127/430408).

Answer (score 3):

You would have to terminate/join the child-process in the `try/except/finaly`-block of the parent thread and afterwards reinvoke it.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) to an older SO-post, which discusses the "killing" of a thread.

Comment: Is there any example code that I could see on how to implement this?