# thread.start_new_thread: transfer exception to main-thread

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Catch a thread’s exception in the caller thread in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829329/catch-a-threads-exception-in-the-caller-thread-in-python)

I have a given code and there is a

```
thread.start_new_thread()
```

As I just read in python doc: "When the function terminates with an unhandled exception, a stack trace is printed and then the thread exits (but other threads continue to run)."
But I want to terminate also the main-thread when the (new) function terminates with an exception - So the exception shall be transfered to the main-thread. How can I do this?

edit:
here is part of my code:

```
def CaptureRegionAsync(region=SCREEN, name="Region", asyncDelay=None, subDir="de"):
    if asyncDelay is None:
        CaptureRegion(region, name, subDir)
    else:
        thread.start_new_thread(_CaptureRegionAsync, (region, name, asyncDelay, subDir))

def _CaptureRegionAsync(region, name, asyncDelay, subDir):
    time.sleep(max(0, asyncDelay))
    CaptureRegion(region, name, subDir)

def CaptureRegion(region=SCREEN, name="Region", subDir="de"):
    ...
    if found:
        return
    else:
        raise Exception(u"[warn] Screenshot has changed: %s" % filename)

CaptureRegionAsync(myregion,"name",2)
```

Comment: Seems another problem to me, not a duplicate. If "a given code" means "third-party code that can not be modified", the problem is totally different.

Comment: Sorry, "a given code" means that I didn't write it and so I'm not very familiar with it - but I can modify it.

Comment: Then my first answer is not to your question, and monkey patching thread is a bad idea. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** It is not the best solution as your question is different from what I thought it is: I expected you were trying to deal with an exception in thread code you can not modify. However, i decided not to delete the answer.

It's hard to catch an exception from another thread. Usually it should be transferred manually.

Can you wrap a thread function? If you wrap the worker thread that crashes into try...except, then you may perform actions needed to exit main thread in `except` block (`sys.exit` seems to be useless, though it's a surprise to me, but there is `thread.interrupt_main()` and `os.abort()`, though you may need  something more graceful like setting a flag the main thread is checking regularly).

However, if you can not wrap the function (can not modify the third-party code calling `start_new_thread`), you may try monkey patching the thread module (or the third-party module itself). Patched version of `start_new_thread()` should wrap the function you worry about:

```
import thread
import sys
import time

def t():
    print "Thread started"
    raise Exception("t Kaboom")

def t1():
    print "Thread started"
    raise Exception("t1 Kaboom")


def decorate(s_n_t):
    def decorated(f, a, kw={}):
        if f != t:
            return s_n_t(f, a, kw)
        def thunk(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                f(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                print "Kaboom"
                thread.interrupt_main() # or os.abort()
        return s_n_t(thunk, a, kw)
    return decorated

# Now let's do monkey patching:
thread.start_new_thread = decorate(thread.start_new_thread)

thread.start_new_thread(t1, ())
time.sleep(5)
thread.start_new_thread(t, ())
time.sleep(5)
```

Here an exception in `t()` causes `thread.interrupt_main()`/`os.abort()`. Other thread functions in the application are not affected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! sys.exit() in the new_thread doesn't kill the main-thread: "sys.exit() [...] will only exit the process when called from the main thread [...]" (http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) So it does not work for me. I edited my first post and added a part of my code.

Comment: Wow... really, it itself raises an exception...

Comment: Fixed it to use thread.interrupt_main()