# How to catch thread error of python from caller?

Tags: python, multithreading

I've searched some answer ,like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829329/catch-a-threads-exception-in-the-caller-thread-in-python)

But my problem is that , I can't modify the code of the caller.

Suppose i have a function `process()` import from other module, and this function will start three threads, and finally return.I can't modify the codes of `process()`, so how can i catch exceptions of the three threads?
Is there any possibility?

Comment: Do you mean catching each thread's exceptions separately? Because if not you can just wrap the call to process() with try

Comment: Actually, crash the process() itself if any thread fail is also acceptable. but it won't!!!! because even thread fail, process() will still return without any error

Comment: Can't you change process() 's code?

Comment: @ShayNehmad No, that's the key problem

Comment: So I think that this is unfortunately impossible