# Python ThreadPoolExecutor Suppress Exceptions

Tags: python, exception

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait, ALL_COMPLETED


def div_zero(x):
    print('In div_zero')
    return x / 0


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    futures = executor.submit(div_zero, 1)

    done, _ = wait([futures], return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
    # print(done.pop().result())

    print('Done')
```

The program above will run to completion without any error message.

You can only get the exception if you explicitly call `future.result()` or `future.exception()`, like what I did in the line commented-out.

I wonder why this Python module chose this kind of behavior even if it hides problems. Because of this, I spent hours debugging
a programming error (referencing a non-exist attribute in a class) that would otherwise be very obvious if the program just crashes with exception, like Java for instance.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @James Why that module silences exceptions by default? This behavior is different from that in many other languages.

Comment: Related: [Catch a thread's exception in the caller thread in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829329/catch-a-threads-exception-in-the-caller-thread-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the reason is so that the entire pool does not crash because of one thread raising an exception. This way, the pool will process all the tasks and you can get the threads that raised exceptions separately if you need to.

Comment: It doesn't need to crash, I think it should at least throw the exceptions to stderr like Java does.

Answer (score 2):

Each thread is (mostly) isolated from the other threads, including the primary thread.  The primary thread does not communicate with the other threads *until you ask it to do so*.

This includes errors.  The result is what you are seeing, the errors occurring other threads do not interfere with the primary thread.  You only need to handle them when you ask for the results.

Comment: But each thread can raise its own exceptions and output to stderr like Java does, instead of silent them.

Comment: @JFreebird It seems to me that your question is why isn't python like Java, more than anything else. I don't think anyone can answer that to your satisfaction.