# How to catch an exception which occured in a thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

*Note: there is [one exact answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779560/903011) to my question in the duplicate (also see my answer below for the modified code). Thank you @quamrana for the pointer*

**Context:** I have a list of methods in a class which are all started in threads. Some of these methods are expected to raise exceptions and these exceptions must be handled in the main program (= not in the method itself).

**The problem:** the exception is not caught and the interpretation (success / failure) is wrong as all threads are "successful".

**What I thought would have worked**: a `try`/`except` in which the thread is actually `start()`.

Please note in the Traceback that both answers are `(...) was successful` as if the `try` only handled the mere fact of starting the thread (`.start()`) and not what is happening in the thread itself.

```
import threading

class Checks:

    @staticmethod
    def isok():
        print("OK")

    @staticmethod
    def isko():
        raise Exception("KO")

# db will keep a map of method names in Check with the actual (executable) method
db = {}

# getting all the methods from Checks, without the built_in ones
for check in [k for k in dir(Checks) if not k.startswith('_')]:
    # create a thread for the method
    db[check] = threading.Thread(target=getattr(Checks, check))
    try:
        # start the thread
        db[check].start()
    except Exception:
        print(f"{check} raised an exception")
    else:
        print(f"{check} was successful")

# wait for all the threads to be finished
for thread in db.keys():
    db[thread].join()

# all the threads are finished at that point
print("all threads are done")
```

The output:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\yop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/yop/.PyCharm2019.2/config/scratches/scratch_6.py", line 11, in isko
    raise Exception("KO")
Exception: KO

isko was successful
OK
isok was successful
all threads are done
```

(the Traceback will be mixed with the actual output of the program, due to the threads but the sequence is always the same)

EDIT: following up on a comment I want to highlight again that the exceptions will occur in the methods but must be caught in the main program (= not handled in the methods themselves).

In a non-threaded approach it is easy: the `try`/`exception` clause in code similar to the one above would catch them as they bubble up.

Comment: You can use `logging` to log errors in thread.

Comment: Or you can use some thread safe data structure to store errors and then read in main.

Comment: @JayVasant: due to the nature of the methods, as I mentioned in the question, the exceptions must be caught in the main program (the fact that they happen trigger further actions in the real case)

Comment: traceback each and every function

Comment: @SaisivaA: I do not understand how exactly to do that? (you could maybe put that in an answer?)

Comment: Instead of placing the print function,  import the module traceback.  And use function traceback.format_exc().

Comment: @quamrana: thank you very much. My question is indeed a duplicate (and I will mark it as it) and the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779560/903011 was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: Starting the thread isn't what fails, so a try-except that only catches exceptions from `start` is never going to work.

Comment: Can you point out what could go wrong in case of this ans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58764003/7870866

Comment: @JayVasant: I specifically mentioned (twice: once in the initial question, and then another time in the extra edit) in my question that the exceptions must be handled at the level of the main program, not in the methods. Your answer does the `try` in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact answer to my problem was given in [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779560/903011) (I marked mine as duplicate, but it is really that particular answer which is perfect in my context).

The code in my question modified to account for the solution:

```
import concurrent.futures

class Checks:

    @staticmethod
    def isok():
        print("OK")

    @staticmethod
    def isko():
        raise Exception("KO")

# db will keep a map of method namles in Check with the actual (executable) method
db = {}

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    for check in [k for k in dir(Checks) if not k.startswith('_')]:
        db[check] = executor.submit(getattr(Checks, check))
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed([db[k] for k in db.keys()]):
        if future.exception():
            print(f"{str(future.exception())} was raised (I do not know where, somewhere)")
        else:
            print("success (again, I do not know where, exactly)")

# all the threads are finished at that point
print("all threads are done")
```

I do not know how to get the name of the future which raised the exception (I will ask [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766707/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-analyzed-completed-future-in-concurrent-futures) about that)

Answer (score 0):

create a queue to catch exceptions.

`errors = queue.Queue()`

```
def threaded_func():
  try:
    # perform some task
  except:
    errors.put(  
      # push into queue as required
    )
```

```
def main():
  while True and threads_running:
   if errors.__len__():
     error_in_main = errors.pop()
     # handle the error as required.
```

Using this manner you can almost immideately catch errors in main thread and perform operations as required.