# How to get the name of the analyzed completed future in concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

While looking for an answer to my question (a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58766392/903011) is available in one answer in the linked duplicate), I discovered `concurrent.futures`, and specifically [`concurrent.futures.as_completed`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58766392/903011).

The code I ended up with (for the context: I needed to catch in the main program exceptions raised in threads started from that main program) works fine, except that I do not know how how to re-attach to the name of the function being scrutinized in `concurrent.futures.as_completed`:

```
import concurrent.futures

class Checks:

    @staticmethod
    def isok():
        print("OK")

    @staticmethod
    def isko():
        raise Exception("KO")

# db will keep a map of method names in Check with the thread handler
db = {}

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    # get the names of the methods in Check, discarding the built-ion ones
    for check in [k for k in dir(Checks) if not k.startswith('_')]:
        db[check] = executor.submit(getattr(Checks, check))

# at that point I have a map of function_name_as_a_string -> thread handler
for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed([db[k] for k in db.keys()]):
    if future.exception():
        print(f"{str(future.exception())} was raised (I do not know where, somewhere)")
    else:
        print("success (again, I do not know where, exactly)")

# all the threads are finished at that point
print("all threads are done")
```

In the success/failure outputs, I know that a method raisod or not an exception. What I do not know is which one did what.

**Since the iteration has to be over the thread handlers I could not find a way to "inject" the method name in the loop to use it in the `print()` - how can I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and create an iterator of (name, handler) tuples:

```
import concurrent.futures

class Checks:

    @staticmethod
    def isok():
        print("OK")

    @staticmethod
    def isko():
        raise Exception("KO")

# db will keep a map of method namles in Check with the actual (executable) method
db = {}

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    for check in [k for k in dir(Checks) if not k.startswith('_')]:
        db[check] = executor.submit(getattr(Checks, check))

for name, handler in zip(db.keys(), concurrent.futures.as_completed([db[k] for k in db.keys()])):
    if handler.exception():
        print(f"{str(handler.exception())} was raised by {name}")
    else:
        print(f"success in {name}")

# all the threads are finished at that point
print("all threads are done")
```