# How to handle exception in threads Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have two threads which are calling a function and that function is creating one more thread.

```
def run(urls):
    while len(urls) != 0:
        t3 = threading.Thread(target=scrap_matches, args=(urls[-1],))
        try:
            print("URL left", threading.currentThread().getName(), len(urls))
            t3.start()
            del urls[-1]
        except:
            print("Got Exception")


part_1, part_2 = parse(urls)

print(part_1)
print(part_2)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(part_1,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(part_2,))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

part_1 and part_2 are lists.
When I got exception in function scrap_matches then instead of catching exception, thread breaks.
I have searched a lot and I find few solutions but those are out of scope of my knowledge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch a thread's exception in the caller thread in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829329/catch-a-threads-exception-in-the-caller-thread-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor:



threads = []

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executer:

    t1 = executer.submit(run, part_1)
    t2 = executer.submit(rn, part_2)
    
    threads.append(t1)
    threads.append(t2)


    for thread in threads:
        try:
            thread.result()
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
```