# How to assert that exception is thrown in a Thread based class in Python unit tests

Tags: python, pytest, python-multithreading, python-unittest

I have code similar to the following written in python - a thread based class

```
from threading import Thread

class ThreadClass(Thread):

    def __init__(self, li):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__()
        self.li = li
        self.ps = list()

    def __validate(self, val):
        if val > 10:
            raise ValueError("Given value is greater than 10")

        return val % 10
    
    def __fun(self):
        ps = list()
        for i in self.li:
            p = self.__validate(i)
            ps.append(p)
        self.ps = ps
    
    def get_ps(self):
        return self.ps

    def run(self):
        self.__fun()
```

And the following unit test to test a failure scenario

```
from unittest import TestCase
from thread_class import ThreadClass

class TestThreadClassNegative(TestCase):

    def test_val_greater_than_valid_fail(self):
        get_data = ThreadClass(li = [2,3,5,11,6])
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            get_data.start()
            get_data.join()
```

The above test fails saying `AssertionError: ValueError not raised` But I can clearly see the exception being raised.

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________ TestThreadClassNegative.test_val_greater_than_valid_fail ___________
[gw0] win32 -- Python 3.7.10 C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\python.exe

self = <tests.unit.test_thread_class.TestThreadClassNegative testMethod=test_val_greater_than_valid_fail>

    def test_val_greater_than_valid_fail(self):
        get_data = ThreadClass(li=[2, 3, 5, 11, 6])
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            get_data.start()
>           get_data.join()
E           AssertionError: ValueError not raised

test_thread_class.py:9: AssertionError
---------------------------- Captured stderr call -----------------------------
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\<user>\projects\pytest_project\thread_class.py", line 27, in run
    self.__fun()
  File "C:\Users\<user>\projects\pytest_project\thread_class.py", line 19, in __fun
    p = self.__validate(i)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\projects\pytest_project\thread_class.py", line 12, in __validate
    raise ValueError("Given value is greater than 10")
ValueError: Given value is greater than 10
```

Why is that test case failing? What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is being raised in the child thread, terminates it, and thats the end for it.

That's because an exception raised in a child thread will not propagate to the caller thread.

A possible solution will be creating a class to catch the exception in run() and raise it in join():

EDIT: I messed up the subclassing, tested it this time, should work

```
class Propogate(Thread):
    def __init__(self, cls):
        super().__init__(target=cls.run)
        self.ex = None

    def run(self):
        try:
            self._target()
        except BaseException as e:
            self.ex = e

    def join(self):
        super().join()
        if self.ex is not None:
            raise self.ex
```

Usage by changing this line:

```
get_data = Propogate(ThreadClass(li = [2,3,5,11,6]))
```

And not inheriting from Thread on the other class:

```
class ThreadClass():
```

My answer is adapted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31614591/11267395)

Comment: When I try this, I am getting another error - `RuntimeError: cannot join thread before it is started`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a derived class to manage exceptions thrown in your thread, a simpler approach is to catch any exceptions within the thread, and then return the exception object, so that it can be handled in the main thread.

```py
def main_function():
    thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
    run_thread_fns = {thread_pool.submit(run_thread_fn, foo, bar, baz): (foo, bar, baz) for (foo, bar, baz) in thread_arg_list}

    for future in as_completed(run_thread_fns):
        result_ex = future.result()
        if result_ex is not None:
            raise result_ex  # or otherwise handle exception

def run_thread_fn(foo, bar, baz):
    try:
        ...  # your code
        return None
    except Exception as ex:
        return ex
```