# Is it possible to wait for Try Else Block execution with threading?

Tags: python, multithreading

In the below code attached is there any way I can wait for else block print statement to get executed ***only after threading is done***  currently
as the function **gg** is threaded I am getting output

```
HelloNothing went wrong

Hello
```

Expected output

```
Hello
Hello
Nothing went wrong
```

Current code

```
import threading
import time 


def gg():
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Hello")

try:
    threading.Thread(target=gg).start()
except:
    print("Something went wrong")
else:
    print("Nothing went wrong")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch a thread's exception in the caller thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829329/catch-a-threads-exception-in-the-caller-thread)

Comment: no i am not trying to catch exception here i m looking for execution of else statemet only when try is finished completly

Answer (score 0):

You can use Join method

```
import threading
import time


def gg():
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Hello")


t1 = threading.Thread(target=gg)
try:
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
except:
    print("Something went wrong")
else:
    print("Nothing went wrong")
```