# Exception was not raised when writing csv ouput polars inside try except

Tags: python

I have a class that contains line of code within try except for function. If there's a general error like if the columns aren't matched to `yaml` it will raise an error and pass the error message into my `progress_label` like this
[image]

I built the simple tool with `tkinter`. When submit button is clicked the `progress_label` shows `Loading . . .` and if it finds an error, it will pop up like the example above. The problem is sometimes it doesn't raise the error message at all so the `progress_label` will keep showing `Loading . . .` when it's supposed to be raised the error message. One of the examples, when I debug is when I found an error like this. It raises error in the backend (cmd or interpreter) but didn't get into the except statement thus the label keeps showing `Loading . . .` instead of any error.

[image]

Meanwhile there's kind of errors that got caught by try and thrown into except statement and this is the example of the error that got into exception, you can see the difference from above screenshot that below shows `ERROR with message`
[image]

```
class IngestGenerator:
    def __init__(self, fn,fd,n3pl):
        self.filename = fn
        self.filedir = fd
        self.name3pl = n3pl
    
    def generate_result_csv(self):
        """To extend 3PL please refer to comment with <(extend this)> note
           Don't forget to extend the yaml when extending 3PL
        """
        
        start_time = time.time()

        # with open("columns 1a.yaml", 'r') as f:
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'columns 1a.yaml'), 'r') as f:
            data = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)

        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
            try :
                # create new list if there's new 3pl behavior (extend this)
                list_type_like = [data['behavior']['type_like'][i]['name3pl'] for i in range(0,len(data['behavior']['type_like']))] #collects names of 3pl which have categorical column to be divided based on
                
                status = False
                for i in range(0,len(data['behavior']['type_like'])):
                    if data['behavior']['type_like'][i]['name3pl']==self.name3pl: #get the name of category column and the values of categories (extend this whole if-statement)
                        list_types = data['behavior']['type_like'][i]['cats']
                        cat_column = data['behavior']['type_like'][i]['categorical_col']
                        status = True
                    else : pass
                if status == False: #for logging to check if its in the list of type-like 3pl (extend this whole if else statement)
                    print("3PL cannot be found on type-like 3PL list")
                else: print("3PL can be found on type-like 3PL list")

                try:
                    for cat in list_types: #dynamic list creation for each category (extend this line only)
                        globals()[f"{cat}_final_df"] = []
                except : print("3pl isn't split based on it's categories")

                xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
                print("Cast to CSV first (win32com)")
                wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(self.filename,ReadOnly=1)
                xl.DisplayAlerts = False
                xl.Visible = False
                xl.ScreenUpdating = False
                xl.EnableEvents = False
                sheet_names = [sheet.Name for sheet in wb.Sheets if sheet.Name.lower() != 'summary']
                print("Sheet names")
                print(sheet_names)

                for sheet_name in sheet_names:
                    print("Reading sheet "+sheet_name)
                    ws = wb.Worksheets(sheet_name)
                    ws.SaveAs(tmpdirname+"\\myfile_tmp_{}.csv".format(sheet_name), 24)

                    used_columns = data['sls_data'][f'{self.name3pl.lower()}_used_columns']
                    renamed_columns = data['sls_data'][f'{self.name3pl.lower()}_rename_columns']
                    rowskip = data['behavior']['row_skip'][f'{self.name3pl.lower()}']
                    list_dtypes = [str for u in used_columns]
                    print("CP 1")

                    scandf = pl.scan_csv(tmpdirname+"\\myfile_tmp_{}.csv".format(sheet_name),skip_rows= rowskip,n_rows=10) #scan csv to get column name
                    print(scandf.columns)
                    scanned_cols = scandf.columns.copy()
                    used_cols_inDF = [] #collects column names dynamically
                    for i in range(0,len(used_columns)):
                        if type(used_columns[i]) is list: #check for each scanned-columns which contained in yaml used_columns, append if the scanned columns exist in yaml
                            for sc in scanned_cols:
                                for uc in used_columns[i]:
                                    if sc == uc:
                                        print(f"Column match : {uc}")
                                        used_cols_inDF.append(uc)
                                    else:pass       
                        else:
                            for sc in scanned_cols: #purpose is same with the if statement
                                if sc == used_columns[i]:
                                    print(f"Column match : {used_columns[i]}")
                                    used_cols_inDF.append(used_columns[i])
                                else:pass
                    print(used_cols_inDF)
                    """
                    JNT files have everchanging column names. Some files only have Total Ongkir, some only have Total,
                    and some might have Total and Total Ongkir. If both exists then will use column Total Ongkir (extend this if necessary i.e for special cases of 3pl)
                    """
                    if self.name3pl == 'JNT':
                        if "Total" in used_cols_inDF and "Total Ongkir" in used_cols_inDF:
                            used_cols_inDF.remove("Total")
                        else:pass
                    else:pass 
                    
                    pldf_csv = pl.read_csv(tmpdirname+"\\myfile_tmp_{}.csv".format(sheet_name),
                            columns = used_cols_inDF,
                            new_columns = renamed_columns,
                            dtypes = list_dtypes,
                            skip_rows= rowskip
                        ).filter(~pl.fold(acc=True, f=lambda acc, s: acc & s.is_null(), exprs=pl.all(),)) #filter rows with all null values
                    print(pldf_csv)
                    print(pldf_csv.columns)
                    
                    for v in data['sls_data']['add_columns']: #create dynamic columns
                        if "3pl invoice distance (m) (optional)" in v.lower() or "3pl cod amount (optional)" in v.lower():
                            pldf_csv = pldf_csv.with_column(pl.Series(name="{}".format(v),values= np.zeros(shape=pldf_csv.shape[0])))
                        elif "3pl tn (mandatory)" in v.lower() or  "weight (kg) (optional)" in v.lower():
                            pass
                        elif "total fee (3pl) (optional)" in v.lower():
                            pldf_csv = pldf_csv.with_column(pl.col(v).str.replace_all(",","").str.strip().cast(pl.Float64,False).fill_null(0))
                        else : 
                            pldf_csv = pldf_csv.with_column(pl.lit(None).alias(v))
                    print(pldf_csv)
                    
                    endpath = self.filedir+"\{}_{}_{}.csv".format(get_file_name(file_name_appear_label["text"]),sheet_name,"IngestResult").replace('/','\\')
                    if self.name3pl not in list_type_like: #(extend this line only)
                        if self.name3pl == 'JNT': #(extend this line and its statement if necessary i.e for special cases of 3pl)
                            pldf_csv = pldf_csv.with_column((pl.col("Total Fee (3PL) (Optional)")+pl.col("Biaya Asuransi").str.replace_all(",","").str.strip().cast(pl.Float64,False).fill_null(0)).alias("Total Fee (3PL) (Optional)"))
                        else: pass
                        print(pldf_csv)
                        pldf_csv[data['sls_data']['add_columns']].write_csv(endpath,sep='\t')
                    elif self.name3pl in list_type_like: #(extend this line only)
                        for cat in list_types:
                            globals()[f"{cat}_final_df"].append(pldf_csv.filter(pl.col(cat_column).str.contains(cat)))

                if self.name3pl not in list_type_like:
                    pass
                elif self.name3pl in list_type_like:
                    for cat in list_types:
                            globals()[f"{cat}_final_df"] = pl.concat(globals()[f"{cat}_final_df"])
                            print(globals()[f"{cat}_final_df"])
                            globals()[f"endpath_{cat}"] = self.filedir+"\{}_{}_{}.csv".format(get_file_name(file_name_appear_label["text"]),cat,"IngestResult").replace('/','\\')
                            print("done creating paths")
                            globals()[f"{cat}_final_df"][data['sls_data']['add_columns']].write_csv(globals()[f"endpath_{cat}"],sep='\t')
                
                progress_label["text"] = "Successful!"
                submit_btn["state"] = "normal"
                browse_btn["state"] = "normal"
                print("Process finished")
            except Exception as e:
                print("ERROR with message")
                print(e)
                progress_label["text"] = "Failed due to {}".format(e)
            finally : 
                wb.Close(False)

        print("Total exec time : {}".format((time.time()-start_time)/60))
```

```
def file_submit_btn_click():
    if (file_name_appear_label["text"]==""):
        progress_label["text"] = "Please input your file"
    elif option_menu.get() == '':
        progress_label["text"] = "Please select 3pl name"
    else:
        try :
            submit_btn["state"] = "disabled"
            browse_btn["state"] = "disabled"
            progress_label["text"] = "Loading . . ."
            name3pl = option_menu.get()
            ingest = IngestGenerator(file_name,file_path,name3pl)
            print(get_file_name(file_name_appear_label["text"]))
            threading.Thread(target=ingest.generate_result_csv).start()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Please, is there something I missed? and why error like that doesn't get into my except statement? and is there any way to generally get all type of error into the except statement?

Comment: Print the exception stack trace, it will tell you the exact line where the problem happened, and possibly also the cause for it.

Comment: I think from the screenshot that I marked error it's pretty clear that the exception did not raise at all since if it's raised, it will firstly print `ERROR with message` string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829329/catch-a-threads-exception-in-the-caller-thread

Comment: @СергейКох i'm not sure if that helps, almost all errors could be catch by the exception but not that pyo3 panicexception