# How to kill main thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

How can I kill main thread and terminate program? 
Now after throwing *RuntimeError* main thread continue executing

```
def function_terminate():
    raise RuntimeError

def test():
    thr = threading.Timer(5.0, function_terminate, args=())
    thr.start()
    setup()
    sleep(6)
    thr.cancel()
    continue_code()
```

I can't use [thread.interrupt_main()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.interrupt%5Fmain) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854216/raise-unhandled-exceptions-in-a-thread-in-the-main-thread) question because I'm using **threading** module not **thread**

I would be very thankful for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can [os._exit(n)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit), which causes the whole process to exit (in an unclean way). However, you usually have no reason to kill the main thread.

Comment: I'm writting own test framework. So, if test(or some action) executes more that test_timeout time, it should throw some Exception

Comment: Why don't you put the test itself in a thread in join it with test_timeout?

Comment: I also have action_time time. Every function (I have more than 15 functions) should throw some Exception when action_time > function executes time. If I put every function in a thread it will be not nice, I think. Or not?)